# search:search string contains both single and double quote hence forming wrong cts search query

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Facing problem in `search:search`, Forming wrong `cts query`.

**Explanation:**

In search options, grammar quotation is set to `'`

```
<quotation>'</quotation>
```

Search string (first parameter to `search:search`) contains both single(`'`) and double quotes (`"`)

**for example:**

`title:'Linguistique et" sciences de 1'homme'`

title constraint will form `element-value-query`

now the parser will form `element-value-query` of `Linguistique et" sciences de 1` and rest will be `word-query` as the quotation is set to `'`

Even if change the quotation to `"`

```
<quotation>"</quotation>
```

and the search string will be

`title:"Linguistique et" sciences de 1'homme"`

Again `element-value-query` will be formed only for **Linguistique et**

I also tried changing the search string to

`title:'Linguistique et&quot; sciences de 1&apos;homme'`

But the same problem as explained above.

I know this is the expected behavior.

**Is there any solution to the same?**

Comment: Why don't you use any other symbol for quotation?

Comment: That won't be a correct solution. Because another symbol also can occur in the search string.

Comment: Desired output is a single element-value-query with the entire input string? And the search needs to be punctuation-sensitive?

Comment: @BenW Yes desired output is single `element-value-query` with entire input string `Linguistique et" sciences de 1'homme`

Answer (score 3):

> The text between the quotation characters is treated as a phrase. You
>   cannot specify a search that includes the quotation character; for
>   example, to specify a search that includes the double quotation
>   character (the default quotation character), modify your grammar to
>   use a different quotation character.

Therefore, seems like what you are trying to achieve can only be possible if you use a different symbol for quotation.

Comment: Yeah, the parser needs to know how to parse. To make it more palatable though, quotation symbols need not be single characters. If you just need something unambiguous to wrap round the input, then just pick a "symbol" that's not going to be used by coincidence. e.g. DIXIT'S_MAGIC_QUOTATION_MARK_STRING

Answer (score 0):

Consider bypassing parsing altogether, at least for that title. If you have another way of singling out the phrase of title (maybe a separate input field), you could pass it into `search:search` as for instance `additional-query`, or use `search:resolve` with a `cts:query` you constructed yourself.

HTH!